# i18n: How to localize big numbers and or large floating point numbers

Tags: javascript, floating-point, localization, internationalization, number-formatting

In my JS app I have a very big number that could (or not) contain decimal places. An undetermined number of decimal places. A number like: `-11212121332131343141456.12345678901234567`.

So I can't use `BigInt(number).toLocaleString(localeCode)` because the number could contain decimal places. Also I can't use `Intl.NumberFormat(localeCode).format(number)` because at some point it will lose precision for being out of `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` and `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` range or having too many decimals.

How to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Target number could be splitted and parsed separately using `BigInt.toLocaleString(...)`, then glued at the end. Special care should be taken with the decimal part, that should not contain group separator.

I faced this issue and developed this tiny library that helps you localize such numbers: [NumberLocalizer](https://github.com/nachodd/NumberLocalizer)